# different overflow policy for Double and Integer. why?

Tags: java, numbers, double, integer-overflow, double-precision

this code

```
System.out.println(Double.MAX_VALUE+12345 == Double.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+12345 == Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

returns

```
true
false
```

Please clarify this difference.

Comment: This is different to the question you asked an hour ago how?

Comment: @Boris the Spider I have thought that this formulation better for SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules are the same, it's just that `Double.MAX_VALUE` is so large that `12345` is roughly 300 orders of magnitude (10<sup>300</sup> times) smaller. Adding a number that is so much smaller than `Double.MAX_VALUE` does not change its value. Adding a number that is of the same order of magnitude would make a difference, though:

```
Double.MAX_VALUE + 1E300
```

produces a positive infinity result, which is not the same as `Double.MAX_VALUE` ([demo](http://ideone.com/Y3JUQk))

Comment: **The rules are the same** - I think it is wrong because after overflow Integer go to negative and double go to infinity

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of addition to the maximum value differs between int and double in two very significant ways:

1. The difference between each int, other than the maximum, and its immediate successor is 1, regardless of magnitude. The difference between consecutive doubles increases with magnitude. For example, the absolute value of the difference between `Double.MAX_VALUE` and the next double smaller than it is about 2e292. The absolute value of the difference between 1.0 and the next double smaller than it is about 1.1e-16.
2. Every 32-bit bit pattern represents an int number. Some of the 64-bit bit patterns are reserved in double for NaN and infinite values. Adding one to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` wraps around to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Adding a big enough positive number to make a difference to `Double.MAX_VALUE` results in `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`, represented by one of the reserved bit patterns.

`int` is based on 2's complement binary arithmetic. It is designed to be compact, efficient, and to allow very fast simple arithmetic.

`double` has more of a bias towards functionality. Often, floating point arithmetic takes more than one machine cycle. It can afford to have reserved bit patterns, such as the infinities, that require special handling.

Comment: I have a question: Is there between Double.MAX_VALUE and Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY any number?

Comment: @gstackoverflow No. However, when you add a positive number to Double.MAX_VALUE, the result is rounded according to the normal rounding rules, which may result in Double.MAX_VALUE being returned. If you want to probe these issues, look at Math.nextUP and Math.nextAfter.

Comment: I don't understand second argument of Math.nextAfter method meaning

Comment: The second argument controls the direction. The result is between the values of the two arguments, but as close as possible to the first argument. I usually use either Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY (same direction as nextAfter) or Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY (to go in the opposite direction from nextAfter, but 0.0 is also useful to go down in magnitude.